# show/hide dymamic div on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is scenario, I have a php Script that display dynamic data from database. The Number of records fetched from the query can be different from day to day so it is very dynamic.

```
<a href="#" id='link1' class="showhide">This is Div Content 1</a><br>
<div id='content1' class='more'>contents 1</div>

<a href="#" id='link2' class="showhide">This is Div Content 2</a><br>
<div id='content2' class='more'>contents 2</div>

<a href="#" id='link3' class="showhide">This is Div Content 3</a><br>
<div id='content3' class='more'>contents 3</div>


$("#link1").on('click', function(){
        $("#content1").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });



$("#link2").on('click', function(){
        $("#content2").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });


$("#link3").on('click', function(){
        $("#content3").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
```

This is how im doing it now but this is not dynamic. If the number of records would 4 for class showhide. the 4th link will not work.

id: link1,link2,link3 and content1,2,3 are geranted from the php loop and it will unique.

[JsFiddle Showing a Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ukq8b/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably cleaner ways to implement this, but you have all the information you need in the bound function.

```
$('a.showhide').on('click', function(){
    $('#content'+this.id.slice(-1)).slideToggle();
});
```

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/devm33/ysBR6/

Answer (score 1):

```
// jQuery 1.4.3+
$('body').delegate( '.showhide', 'click', function(e){
  $(this).next('.more').slideToggle();
  return false;
});


// jQuery 1.7+
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.showhide', function(e){
  $(this).next('.more').slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

[read about event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-* attributes`

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="showhide" data-toggle="slide" data-target="slide1">
    This is Div Content 3
</a>
<br>
<div class='more' data-more="slide1">contents 3</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('.showhide[data-toggle="slide"]').on('click', function()
{
    $('.more[data-more="' + $(this).data('target') + '"]').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```